# Null pointer exception when attempting to use JNDI for JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, jndi, glassfish-4

In Glassfish admin, I setup a JDBC connection pool that I can ping ok. Also in Glassfish admin, I have setup a JNDI JDBC resource called jdbc/myDb

However I'm unable to connect to it from Java.  I have tried both injection style:

```
@Resource (mappedName="jdbc/myDB")
private DataSource datasource;
```

I have also tried Context style :

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource datasource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDB")
```

All I get is java.lang.NullPointerException.

I have also tried various naming styles such as java:jdbc/myDB  or java:comp/env/jdbc/myDb

This is using the latest Glassfish (4.1), the latest Postgres Driver (9.3-1102 JDBC 41) against Postgres 9.4, and the latest Java (1.8.0_31-b13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to the Menu  JDBC -> JDBC Resources -> jdbc/__default

Choose your DBName at the DropDown Menu "Pool Name: " and use

```
@Resource (mappedName="jdbc/__default")
```

Mind the two "_" !

At least this works for me.

p.s.: Can you specify where the NPE is thrown ?